# how to use double pointer in this situation

Tags: c, pointers, double

```
#include<stdlib.h>



typedef struct HEAP_
{
      int size;

      void **tree;

      int (*compare)( const void *key1,const void *key2);
      void (*destroy) (void *data);
}Heap;

int main()
{
    Heap *H;
    void *temp;

     H=(Heap*)malloc(sizeof(Heap));

     if ((temp = (void **)realloc(H->tree, (5) * sizeof (void *))) == NULL) return -1;
     H->tree=temp;

     int a=0001;
     int b=0002;

    H->tree[0]=&a;
    H->tree[1]=&b;

    //*(int*)H->tree[0]=0001;
    //*(int*)H->tree[1]=0002;

    //printf("%d %d %d %d %d",H->tree[0],H->tree[1],H->tree,*(int*)H->tree[0],*(int*)H->tree[1],*(int*)*H->tree);
    //printf("%d %d %d ",*(int*)H->tree[0],*(int*)H->tree[1],*(int*)*H->tree);
```

these are kinds of outcome i want to figure out when it run out like address and when it run out like the number 
        //printf("%d %d  ",*(int*)H->tree[0],*(int*)H->tree[1]);

```
    printf("%d %d  ", *(int*)H->tree[0] , *(int*)H->tree[1]);


    return 0;
}
```

when i build and run it the compiler told me , the last one cannot be printed  how can i fix it? it seems like i misunderstand the pointer.

Comment: int main()
{
    Heap *H;
    void *temp;

     H=(Heap*)malloc(sizeof(Heap));
     H->tree=NULL;
    if ((temp = (void **)realloc(H->tree, (5) * sizeof (void *))) == NULL) return -1;
    H->tree=temp;

     int *a;  *a=1;
     int *b;  *b=4;

    H->tree[0]=&a;
    H->tree[1]=&b;

   
      printf(" %d\n ", *(int*)*H->tree);
     


    return 0;
}

this  also cannot work

Comment: Why do you malloc `H`? Also please note that numbers such as `0001` are _octal_, which is likely not what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

You have allocated memory for the structure:

```
H=(Heap*)malloc(sizeof(Heap));
```

but you did not allocate memory for its member tree. You need to do this also:

```
H->tree = malloc(required_size);
```

So your working code would look like this:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct HEAP_
{
      int size;
      void **tree;
      int (*compare)( const void *key1,const void *key2);
      void (*destroy) (void *data);
}Heap;

int main() {
        Heap *H; 
        void *temp;
        H=malloc(sizeof(Heap));
        H->tree=NULL;
        if((temp = malloc(5*sizeof(void *))) ==  NULL)
                 return -1; 
        H->tree=temp;
        int a;
        a=1;
        int b;
        b=4;
        H->tree[0]=&a;
        H->tree[1]=&b;
        printf(" %d\n ", *(int *)H->tree[0]);
        printf(" %d\n ", *(int *)H->tree[1]);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: int main()
{
    Heap *H;
    void *temp;

     H=(Heap*)malloc(sizeof(Heap));
     H->tree=NULL;
    if ((temp = (void **)realloc(H->tree, (5) * sizeof (void *))) == NULL) return -1;
    H->tree=temp;

     int *a;  *a=1;
     int *b;  *b=4;

    H->tree[0]=&a;
    H->tree[1]=&b;

   
      printf(" %d\n ", *(int*)*H->tree);
     


    return 0;
}

why this cannot work if I change the a,b into *a *b

Comment: @yuansun your pointer `a` and `b` do not point to a valid location. For starters, you should try using `int a,b;`

Answer (score 0):

```
Here the answer :
```

**you need allocate memory for Heap like below ,**

```
 H=(Heap*)malloc(sizeof(Heap));
```

**You have allocate memory for double pointer too..**

H->tree = malloc(sizeof(int**)*2/* number of pointers*/);

H->tree[0]=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

H->tree[1]=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

**Assign the value to tree[0] like below ,**

```
    *((int*)H->tree[0]) = 25;
```

**Working code is below :**

```
typedef struct HEAP_
{
      int size;

        void **tree;

       int (*compare)( const void *key1,const void *key2);
        void (*destroy) (void *data);
}Heap;

   int main()  
   {  
    Heap *H;  

      H=(Heap*)malloc(sizeof(Heap));  
      H->tree = malloc(sizeof(int**)*2);  
      H->tree[0]=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));  
      H->tree[1]=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));  
      *((int*)H->tree[0]) = 25;

      printf("%d",*((int*)H->tree[0]));


      return 0;
    }
```